# Need help with logarithmic differentiation

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

I need to use logarithmic differentiation to get f(x)=x$\sqrt{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)}$. I've been working on it for a while and could use some help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you calculate the log of the RHS?

Comment: Start with the rule $ln(ab) = ln(a) + ln(b)$, and then use $ln(a^b) = bln(a)$

Comment: You have $\log(f(x)) = (\log(x+1) + \log(x+1) + \log(x+3) + \log(x+4))/2.$  Differentiate and use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)
=x \prod_{k=1}^4 \sqrt{x+k}
$.

$\ln f(x)
=\ln x + \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac12 \ln(x+k)
$.

$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
=(\ln f(x))'
= \frac1{x} + \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac12 \frac1{x+k}
$.

$f'(x)
=f(x)(\ln f(x))'
=f(x)\left(\frac1{x} + \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac12 \frac1{x+k}\right)
=\left(x \prod_{k=1}^4 \sqrt{x+k}\right)\left(\frac1{x} + \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac12 \frac1{x+k}\right)
$.

You can distribute
the left product
over the right sum
as you wish.